# Is there a way to set bootstrap video carousel interval to play the next video when first one is done playing automatically?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 4 video carousel and I would like to have the next video slide into the frame automatically when the first video is done playing. I tried to set the data interval to match video but the second video is longer so that does not solve my issue. Any solution for this?

Matching Data Interval to first video

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 pb-3">
      <div class="video-width-testimonials bg-white shadow-sm rounded p-2 mx-lg-auto">
       <!-- Video Block -->
       <div id="youTubeVideoPlayer" class="video-player">

          <!-- Video Iframe -->
          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe width="500" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*****"  class="vid-one" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen-two></iframe>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*****" class="vid-one" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen-two></iframe>
                        </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          <!-- End Video Iframe -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Video Block -->
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

auto slide to next video when video finished
```

Comment: I believe this may be the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536949/8761016

Comment: Another example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264104/bootstrap-wait-for-the-video-to-finish-before-sliding-to-the-next-carousel